# How to open windows OS host entry file with powershell cmdlet or windows run dialog box?

Tags: windows, powershell, command, powershell-cmdlet

I hope there must be `powershell cmdlet` to open the Windows host entry file. I have checked across the net and I could to find the `windows command` for opening the host entry file, so I can utilize it in `Windows Run Dialog box`

Comment: There isn't a built-in cmdlet for that. What are you [really](https://xyproblem.info/) trying to do? Automate hosts editing so you can test something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows host entry file is just a text file, so all you need to do is:

notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Good point, but please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).